# Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)? in R on Mac

Tags: r

```
sum <- function(data){
  sum(data)
}
median <- function(data){
  median(data)
}
floor <- function(data){
  floor(data)
} 
evaluate <- function(func, dat){

  func(dat)
}
```

This is my code. The goal I want to achieve are as followings

1. evaluate(sum, c(2, 4, 6)) should evaluate to 12;
2. evaluate(median, c(7, 40, 9)) should evaluate to 9;
3. evaluate(floor, 11.1) should evaluate to 11;

But I always got the error as below

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Comment: `sum <- function(data) { base::sum(data) }; evaluate <- function(func, dat) { func(dat) }; evaluate(sum, c(2, 4, 6))`. Your functions are calling themselves without a terminal condition, so you have an infinite recursion. Presumably you want to call the functions from `base`, in which case you need to qualify their names.

Comment: There is already a question about this with essentially the exact same title. You need to research your questions before asking them.

Answer (score -1):

The code should be

```
eval <- function(func, num){
return(func(num))
}

x <- eval(floor, 11.1)
> x
[1] 11
```